# Using "moderncv" package, the \cvitemwithcomment command gives error

Tags: tables, floats, moderncv

I'm trying to create my personal CV using `moderncv` package but I'm getting an error: in language skills section I'd like to insert a table resuming my skills using the code as follows

```
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Italian}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \hline
            Listening         & Reading        & Spoken interaction & Spoken production & -       \\ \hline
            C1                & C1              & C1                 & B2                & B2      \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \hline
            Listening         & Reading        & Spoken interaction & Spoken production & -       \\ \hline
            B2                & B2              & B1                 & B1                & B1      \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}}{}
```

However, while compiling I get these repeated errors:

```
Environment table undefined. \end{table}}{} 
\begin{document} ended by \end{table}. \end{table}}{} 
\begin{minipage} on input line 131 ended by \end{table}. \end{table}}{}
```

and compilation is blocked.
Could someone give me some hint to solve this problem?

Comment: me too! the moderncv class should inherit the `\ecvlanguage{}` command from the `europecv2013` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use float environments, such as `table` or `figure`, in `moderncv`; since it makes no sense to have floating objects in a CV, they are not implemented by the class: notice also that the length `\tabcolsep` is not set by the class, so it has `0pt` as value; you need to change it using something like

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
```

otherwise, there will be no separation between columns in tabular material. Your code with those recommendations:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Languages}
aaaa
\cvitemwithcomment{Italian}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \hline
            Listening         & Reading        & Spoken interaction & Spoken production & -       \\ \hline
            C1                & C1              & C1                 & B2                & B2      \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \hline
            Listening         & Reading        & Spoken interaction & Spoken production & -       \\ \hline
            B2                & B2              & B1                 & B1                & B1      \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }{}

\end{document}
```

As a side note, your tables have too many lines. Here I changed the tables slightly and used the features provided by the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Italian}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \midrule
            & & Spoken & Spoken & \\
            Listening         & Reading        &  interaction &  production & -       \\             C1                & C1              & C1                 & B2                & B2      \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    }{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{%
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{Understanding} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Speaking}          & Writing \\ \midrule
            & & Spoken & Spoken & \\
            Listening         & Reading        & interaction & production & -       \\ \hline
            B2                & B2              & B1                 & B1                & B1      \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    }{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice help Gonzalo! My knowledge of table enviroment didn't help me. The way you showed me looks as I wanted. Muchas gracias! PS: Is there a way to also centering the elements inside each cell of the table?

Comment: @Doc You're welcome! ¡De nada! I am afraid don't inderstand your question, the entries of each cell are already centered. Could you please explain in more detail what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. The entries are centered as you said; my tex compiler just resized the pdf and so the table looked compressed and without centered elements! Thank you again!